# Go to Typescript Source Definition instead of Compiled Definition in Visual Studio Code

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, monorepo

I am working on a typescript project with Visual Studio Code including multiple npm packages structured like this:

- Source code: `/src/index.ts`
- Compiled code: `/dist/...`

When I right click on imported objects and choose "Go to Definition" or click `F12` or by clicking on the object with holding down `CTRL`, Visual Studio Code opens the corresponding `.d.ts` file in `/dist`

[image: vscode go to definition]
[image: vscode open .d.ts]

However, I want VSCode to open the corresponding `.ts` file in `/src`

[image: .ts file]

Is it possible to change this behavior, as it is really annoying to manually search for the source file.

I've created git repo, so that you can try it yourself:
https://github.com/flolude/stackoverflow-typescript-go-to-definition

- you just need to run `yarn bootstrap` in order to replicate the issue.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

TypeScript 2.9 introduced a compilerOption called [declarationMap](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-9.html).  Per the release notes:

> Enabling --declarationMap alongside --declaration causes the compiler
>   to emit .d.ts.map files alongside the output .d.ts files. Language
>   Services can also now understand these map files, and uses them to map
>   declaration-file based definition locations to their original source,
>   when available.
>
> In other words, hitting go-to-definition on a declaration from a .d.ts
>   file generated with --declarationMap will take you to the source file
>   (.ts) location where that declaration was defined, and not to the
>   .d.ts.

I [submitted a PR](https://github.com/flolude/stackoverflow-typescript-go-to-definition/pull/1) on your example repo to enable this setting.

Answer (score 0):

The newer VSCode version (April 2022 or later) supports this with a feature called "Go to Source Definition" (see [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_67#_typescript-47-support)). It is still a work in progress I believe (given [this](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/49003) discussion thread), but should be working properly in most cases.